# Convert T-SQL stored procedure to Oracle

Tags: oracle, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like convert the T-SQL stored procedure below into an Oracle stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
(
    @FirstName nvarchar(20),
    @LastName nvarchar(20)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT p.PersonId,
           p.Address,
           p.FirstName,
           p.LastName
      FROM People p
     WHERE p.FirstName = @FirstName
       AND p.LastName = @LastName
END
GO
```

Comment: So what problem are you encountering in this task?

Comment: I'm new to writing Oracle stored procedures but have a lot of experience with T-SQL. I'd just like to know what this stored procedure would look like in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may convert it to a procedure such like this in oracle :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc
(
    i_FirstName varchar2(20), -- alternatively use People.FirstName%type instead of varchar2(20)
    i_LastName varchar(20),
    o_PersonId out People.PersonId%type,
    o_Address  out People.Address%type,
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT p.PersonId, p.Address
      INTO o_PersonId, o_Address
      FROM People p
     WHERE p.FirstName = i_FirstName
       AND p.LastName = i_LastName;
END;
```

as @a_horse_with_no_name warned, the above one works for single row. You may use the following working for multiple rows also :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc
(
    i_FirstName varchar2(20), -- alternatively use People.FirstName%type instead of varchar2(20)
    i_LastName varchar(20),
    o_PersonId out People.PersonId%type,
    o_Address  out People.Address%type,
) AS
BEGIN
  for c in
   (
    SELECT p.PersonId, p.Address
      FROM People p
     WHERE p.FirstName = i_FirstName
       AND p.LastName = i_LastName
    )
   loop
     o_PersonId := c.PersonId;
     o_Address  := c.Address;
     dbms_output.put_line(' Person id : '||o_PersonId||' - Address : '||o_Address);
   end loop;
END;

SQL> var fname varchar2;
SQL> var lname varchar2;
SQL> exec myProc(:fname,:lname);
SQL> /
```

- You don't need to add `in` keyword before `in` type arguments, but `out` keyword is required for `out` type args.
- If your Oracle database is created using a Unicode character set, an `NVARCHAR` should be migrated to a `VARCHAR2` in Oracle.
- `OR REPLACE` part stands for compiling a stored procedure repeatedly. If omitted, it will raise an error telling you that `object already exists`.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. I have a feeling I've a lot more questions to ask about Oracle, but I'll start new questions for those.

Comment: @JonathanRoberts Note that this only works if the query returns a single row. The SQL Server version can return multiple rows.